System crashes after about 4 hours of heavy GPU usage
I have 2 rtx 3090s running in nlink on an older mainboard with 64GB ram and an i5-9600K. The whole system is powered by a SEASONIC 13000Watt unit, which should be plently. I am using the system to run llama.cpp. But after running it for about 4 hours, the system crashes. Sometimes even after just 2 hours. dmesg is empty. Whenever it happens, the system becomes unresponsive for a few seconds then it displays and error like this.
then it usually restarts after a few more seconds. It's incredibly painful to debug since the crashes take so long and theres little info. The GPU temps are stable, I already tried reinstalling the whole os (ubuntu server) on a fresh ssd and the Memory is not blowing up. Since linux logs no error, I am assuming its either the mainboard or the power supply (although 1300 watt should be more than enough for 2 3090s). I already updated the mainboards bios, aswell as the ssd's bios.
Sometimes the system restarts, other times its in a zombie state where the webserver still respobds with 500 error codes. The logs files are also sometimes filled with /0 characters.
What are some further troubleshooting steps I could take (currently I'm running a single gpu and see if that still crashes it).

Since drive I/O seems to be failing, look for overheating of the SSD or associated chips.

I switched the ssd with a new one already. same issue. I could try a sata ssd.

or associated chips, i.e., chips on the motherboard.

Ended up being a busted Seasonic PSU.
